# C# Looping Messagebox for Exception

Tags: c#, loops, methods, messagebox

## Looping Messagebox!!

**I have a looping Messagebox after an error occurs and im wondering how to fix it. I have tried returning the Calculate() method and i think that's the problem, but im not sure.**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public int division = 0;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private decimal Calculate()
        {
            // This array is to hold the logical operators
            string[] allowed = { "+", "-", "*", "/" };

            // If the right operator is selceted then perform the action and return result
            if (operate.Text == "+")
            {
                decimal division = Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text);                
            }
            else if (operate.Text == "-")
            {
                decimal division = Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text);
            }
            else if (operate.Text == "*")
            {
                decimal division = Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text);
            }
            else if (operate.Text == "/")
            {
                decimal division = (Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text));             
            }
            // if the operator is not something within the array then display message
            else if (!allowed.Contains(operate.Text))
            {
                string msg = string.Format("Not a valid operater {0}Please Enter one of the Following:{0}{1}"
                , Environment.NewLine, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allowed));
                MessageBox.Show(msg);
                operate.Text = "";             
            }
            return Calculate();
        }
```

Comment: You need to declare `division` at the top of your method and return that at the bottom.

Comment: `return Calculate();` Recursively calls the function forever,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
private decimal Calculate()
{
     // This array is to hold the logical operators
     string[] allowed = { "+", "-", "*", "/" };

     decimal result = 0m;
     // If the right operator is selected then perform the action and return result
     if (operate.Text == "+")
     {
          result = Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text);                
     }
     else if (operate.Text == "-")
     {
          result = Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text);
      }
      else if (operate.Text == "*")
      {
          result = Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text);
      }
      else if (operate.Text == "/")
      {
          result  = (Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text));             
      }
      // if the operator is not something within the array then display message
      else if (!allowed.Contains(operate.Text))
      {
          string msg = string.Format("Not a valid operater {0}Please Enter one of the Following:{0}{1}"
        , Environment.NewLine, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allowed));

          MessageBox.Show(msg);

          operate.Text = "";

      }

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

//   Try this

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           result.Text = Calculate().ToString();
        }


        private decimal Calculate() {

            decimal division = 0;

            // This array is to hold the logical operators
        string[] allowed = { "+", "-", "*", "/" };

            // If the right operator is selceted then perform the action and return result
            if (operate.Text == "+")
            {
                 division = Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text);
    }
            else if (operate.Text == "-")
            {
                 division = Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text);
}
            else if (operate.Text == "*")
            {
                 division = Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text);
            }
            else if (operate.Text == "/")
            {
                 division = (Convert.ToDecimal(operand1.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(operand2.Text));
            }
            // if the operator is not something within the array then display message
            else if (!allowed.Contains(operate.Text))
            {
                string msg = string.Format("Not a valid operater {0}Please Enter one of the Following:{0}{1}"
                , Environment.NewLine, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allowed));
MessageBox.Show(msg);
                operate.Text = "";
            }
            return division;
        }

    }
```